# Error when I try importing a react-admin component

Tags: react-admin

The react-admin application is showing me this error:

```
Attempted import error: 'useRecordContext' is not exported from 'react-admin'.
```

This error happens when I'm trying to import a react-admin component or hook react-admin, something like the next image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdoGw.png)

So let me know please if I have to update react-admin versión or anything else, I'm currently using these dependencies according to next image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y92fd.png)

Comment: You need react-admin v4

Comment: Interesting, in that case, the reason is for the version, isn´t it?

Comment: No, I made a mistake, in version v3.19.11 useRecordContext is normally imported.

Comment: Ok I'll check it and confirm you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using react-admin 3.5, and `useRecordContext` didn't exist back then.

I don't know where you found the docs for this hook. I advise you to select the version you're using in the react-admin documentation (in your case, https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.13/Tutorial.html) - there, you'll only see the hooks and components available in your version.

Also, react-admin 3.5 is more than 2 years old. 20 minor versions and one major version were published since then. I strongly advise you to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it and go back here to review the comments again